# freopen does not write the data until my application closes

Tags: c++, c, qt

I am writing a Qt GUI application (for doing XSL transformations). To print error messages to a file I am using a call like:

```
freopen("my-error-file.txt", "w", stderr);
// call to libxslt function, which possibly prints to stderr
fclose(stderr);
```

The problem I'm having is that while my-error-file.txt is created immediately, it doesn't have any content. When I close the application, then the error content is written to the file. I assume that is proper behavior, but the behavior that I actually want is that that my-error-file.txt written to and closed immediately, whether the GUI window is closed or not.

Am I missing a function call?

I tried `fflush(stderr)`, but to no effect.

Comment: So the file is not flushed even when you call fflush/fclose? Are you sure? Did you debug this, did you step over the call to fflush/fclose in the debugger, and then open the file in notepad immediately? Try adding `fprintf(stderr, "TEST 123"); fflush(stderr); QMessageBox::warning(this, "", "Flushed!");` and see the file when the message box pops up.

Comment: fflush after every write to the file should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a goober. I was calling fflush before fclose, but the function was returning before those functions were called.